# Mouse hover using jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

Hi My code in content editor web part is something like below

But I am getting description for all hyperlinks even if i mouse over on first item. Please let me know how to change the code in  such a way so that it only displays the discription of the item iam hovering on. Please let me know if i am not clear.

My code from XSL:

Thanks,

Comment: Please give a sample of the HTML where .divTitleLink and .divDescription reside.

Comment: You are just using a class selector, so all elements with that class in the document will be displayed. It would be useful to see your html, as I you probably need to select the correct element here by looking at the nestings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your markup look like this :

```
<div class="divTitleLink">
  <a>Your First link</a>
  <div class="divDescription">Your First Description</div>
</div>
<div class="divTitleLink">
  <a>Your Second link</a>
  <div class="divDescription">Your SecondDescription</div>
</div>
...
```

Then, in your javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').hover(
      function () {
        $(this).parent('div').find('.divDescription').show();
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).parent('div').find('.divDescription').hide();
      }
   );
  });
```

If I guessed the markup wrong, then you can adjust it using the [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) functions in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked for me. I will let you know if i encounter any problem.Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Can I control the speed of the hover? If so, can you please tell me how to use the hover() that way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like the following, but can you share your current markup?

Your example markup (given in an answer below) appears to simplify to:

```
<div class="divTitleLink">
    <a target="_blank"> ... Link 1 </a>
</div>
<div class="divDescription">
    ... Description 1
</div>
<div class="divTitleLink">
    <a target="_blank"> ... Link 2 </a>
</div>
<div class="divDescription">
    ... Description 2
</div>
<div class="divTitleLink">
    <a target="_blank"> ... Link 3 </a>
</div>
<div class="divDescription">
    ... Description 3
</div>
```

The jQuery to do what you're trying to do would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.divTitleLink a').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).parents('.divTitleLink').next('.divDescription').show();
            },
            function () {
                $(this).parents('.divTitleLink').next('.divDescription').hide();
            } 
        ); 
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question

Comment: I would like to display divdescription when i hover on link. But with your code I will be hiding the link.

Comment: you just could use '.toggle()'

Comment: @user346514 you need to post some of your HTML, otherwise we have no idea what the relationship between the `a` and `.divDescription` is.